# Install kube-dns using github file"kube-dns.yaml.sed" get error "CrashLoopBackOff"

Tags: kubernetes

```
$ kubectl logs -n kube-system po/kube-dns-5d6f4dbccf-gt5j2
Error from server (BadRequest): a container name must be specified for pod kube-dns-5d6f4dbccf-gt5j2, choose one of: [kubedns dnsmasq sidecar]

root@k8s-server01:~/source/dns# kubectl logs -n kube-system po/kube-dns-5d6f4dbccf-gt5j2 -c kubedns
I1101 01:49:49.294664       1 dns.go:48] version: 1.14.10
F1101 01:49:49.364594       1 server.go:56] Failed to create a kubernetes client: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Where did you get that yaml file?

Comment: we need more details here, provide us steps that led you to this error, as 
@rico said, where did you get that yaml from, did you follow some kind of a tutorial?

Comment: well,i get it from "https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns/kube-dns/kube-dns.yaml.sed" ,and modified the parameter "$DNS_SERVER_IP","$DNS_DOMAIN" and change image source from 'k8s.gcr.io' to 'registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers',  then run "kubectl create -f kube-dns.yaml" get that error.

Comment: In my case, I had to put numeric IP on "--kube-master-url=http://X.X.X.X:8080". It's on yaml file of RC (ReplicationController), just like:

    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubedns
    ...
        args:
        # command = "/kube-dns"
        - --domain=cluster.local
        - --dns-port=10053
        - --kube-master-url=http://192.168.99.100:8080